# when using chrome code inspector, I lose access to the most recent stylesheet

Tags: css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, web-inspector

Using Dreamweaver to create a static webpage using a separate stylesheet.

I make a change to use CSS grid for a particular section of the webpage.

In the desktop viewport, the CSS grid works fine:

```
.grid {display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; column-gap: 2em}
.grid-item {display: inline-grid; }
```

So I see a 2 x 2 grid when using 4 x `.grid-item`.

I recently added a CSS rule into the stylesheet:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .grid {grid-template-columns: 1fr;}
}
```

with the intent that 600px and less, the grid would display in 1 column.

When in the desktop viewport I use the Chrome Inspector, the grid behaviour disappears, even though I am still seeing the same page which hasn't reloaded and it is in desktop viewport.

I also fail to see the expected behaviour when the viewport width is 600px or less.

It seems that when I use the Chrome or new Edge Inspector, the stylesheet reverts back to an older version of the stylesheet which doesn't contain the grid CSS - it doesn't show in Inspector.

Same behaviour occurs in an Incognito behaviour.

Help appreciated.

Comment: It's not possible, when you open browser inspector stylesheet does not change unless you are loading stylesheet depending on the view port width/height/orientation.

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti, if what I describe happens exactly as I describe it, it can happen. Can you please try loading [https://s.doig.com.au/edu/](https://s.doig.com.au/edu/) and see if the text under Campaigns is in a 2 x 2 grid, and the Campaigns section has a photo background? Now, try inspecting the Campaigns section, and see if the photo background disappears, and grid disappears too (in desktop viewport).

Comment: @Steve I opened the link you shared, I found no issue in it, I'm using Monitor with 1980x1080 resolution, here are the link to the screenshots of what I observed while inspecting the site: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sg1jMWn6dqc9HAtL0eNJo0h0vobM-jKP?usp=sharing

Comment: That's great @PrathameshKoshti, can you think why my webpage would revert to the old stylesheet when using Inspector in Chrome?

Comment: @Steve I'm not really sure but it could be the cache issue, try clearing the browser cache and try again, it might work.